# GraphName() private access Error in rosjava_core

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I created my own new package and took the Talker and Listener code from pubsub tutorial pkg.I build it using "gradle build" command I get error for both Talker and Listener:
my_workspace/test_java_core/src/main/java/org/ros/test_java_core/Listener.java:28: GraphName(java.lang.String) has private access in org.ros.namespace.GraphName return new GraphName("test_java_core/listener"); I took listener and talker from pubsub tutorial.
how to fix it? Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47142/graphname()-private-access-error-in-rosjava_core/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "Getting Started" page is a little outdated on that point. Instead of:

```
return new GraphName("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener");
```

you should use:

```
return GraphName.of("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener");
```

The `rosjava_tutorial_pubsub` package already has these changes.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-31**:
it builds but it does not creat ".classpath",".project" files and ".settings/"directory as in pubsub pkg. Because I cannot run it I execute "./build/install/test_java_core/bin/test_java_core org.ros.test_java_core.Talker" get error:"./build/install/test_java_core/bin/test_java_core: Data not found"

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-31**:
add

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

to your build.gradle, run `gradle eclipse`.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-31**:
It builds and now the files are also made but it gives the same  which I mentioned above when I apply command "./build/install/test_java_core/bin/test_java_core org.ros.test_java". Do I need to add something in baschrc? I dont know why it cannot find /build/install/test_java_core/bin/test_java_core.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-11-02**:
Hi Martin, Could you please answer my query http://answers.ros.org/question/47312/do-i-need-to-add-jar-path-in-buildgradle/  Thank you very much